# When to use Label encoding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-encoding, labeling

All the articles I read, it is clear that, Label Encoding should be avoided for the ordinal data. But, in one of my ML tutorial video of `Artificial Neural Network`, the **Gender** column (having two values, *male* or *female*) is Label Encoded.

I wonder this is a bad approach.

**Can I use label encoding for any column which is having only two possible values without any priority issue (the model can think one of the value is having higher priority)?**

Comment: By "label encoding", do you mean converting categorical unordered values to integers?

Comment: Yes, gender is a nominal variable